# Touch button when I touch TextView

Tags: android, button

I have a little problem. I have button with textview beside it. I want to touch the button when the textview is touched (effect: button is highlighted when I touch the button). Is there some easy way to do this? I cannot find any appriopriate function.

Edit: Okay, I've fixed my problem. It is:

hilfeText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            int action = me.getAction();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                hilfe.setPressed(true);
                return true;
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                hilfe.setPressed(false);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the click and focus mode of a `button` in `xml` file
like
`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/recordings_icon" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/recordings_glow" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/recordings_shadow" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/recordings_icon" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

you can put this file in a directory name `drawables`
`@drawable/recordings_icon` is an image file 
you just declare this filename as background for `button` layout xml file
`<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonActivate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/xmlfilename" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `performClick()` method using `Button reference` inside `onClick` of `TextView`.

example-

```
myTextView.setOnClickListner(){

    public void onClick(){
       myButton.performClick();

        --------------code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup an `onClickListener` for your `Button` and `TextView` and in the `onClick()`, let them both call the same function. Simple.

Comment: I didn't ask for clicking the button. I asked for touching it. Clicking doesn't have any duration, so it doesn't highlight my button at all.

Comment: Just setonTouchListener for both button and textview and implement the same in onTouch() function. But I don't recommend doing that because 3-times the touch will be called- One for Action-UP,DOWN, and MOVE

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
TextView v = ...;
final Button b = ...;
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       b.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
       b.requestFocus();
       b.performClick();
    }
});
```